# arrow function in template literals is printed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

In a function named "Car" I added a method, "beep", with an optional message input:

```js
this.beep = function (message) { }
```

I want to use template literals in order to log this inside the function:

```js
console.log(this.name + ': ' + 'Beeeeep!' + (message ? ' ' + message : ''))
```

I wrote the following, but the output shows me the content of the literals themselves:

```js
console.log(`${this.name}: Beeeeep! ${ (message) => {
  if (message) return `${message}`;
    return ' ';
  }}`);
```

Outputs (for this.name='myCar'):

```js
myCar: Beeeeep! (message) => {
    if (message) return `${message}`;
    return '';
  }
```

Why does it log the content of the literal instead of transpile it?

---

*I figured out how to write it in a simpler way that works as well:

```js
console.log(`${this.name}: Beeeeep! ${message || ''}`)
```

But I still want to understand what was wrong in the first code.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you are passing the body and definition of the function to the string of template literal. If you want the result of the function to be shown in the string, you should use and invoke the function at the same time unless it would be passed as a string containing the body of that function. To achieve this, you can use IIFE.

```
console.log(`${this.name}: Beeeeep! ${((message) => {
  if (message) return `${message}`;
  return ' ';
})()}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because your implementation merely defines a function, so the template literal prints the function itself.

You want to print the output of the function, so you need to call the arrow function. I've changed your function to use a ternary operator, and also used an IIFE to invoke the function so its output is printed as desired.

```js
console.log(`${this.name}: Beeeeep!  ${((message) => message ? message : ' ')('Test')}`);
```